# Excel Conditional Formatting Identify specific rows

Tags: excel, regex, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

My Result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I tried one formula to identify the specific rows the rule 1: first,last name should be same and source full name is different and contains `NORTH CAROLINA ADMINISTRATIVE OFFICE` it should be highlighted

Rule 2: if first,last name is same and source full name is is different doesn't contain `NORTH CAROLINA ADMINISTRATIVE OFFICE` should not be highlighted

the formula i tried is

```
=OR(AND($E2=$E1,$B2<>$B1,$D2=$D1),AND($E2=$E3,$B2<>$B3,$D2=$D3))
```

is that possible can anyone help?

Comment: I think it is better to use an auxiliary column in which you write the formula, for example in column G. There you first check if you get a correct result (True/False). After you work on the logic you want and get a correct result, you can then use conditional formatting based on the value in the auxiliary column.

Comment: Is all your data sorted by name. The example you show *is*, but is that always the case?

Comment: i used conditional formatting to higlight the rows with colour

Answer (score 1):

For this example put in cell J1 the value: NORTH CAROLINA ADMINISTRATIVE OFFICE

put in G2 the formula below:

```
=IF(OR(AND(D2=D1,E2=E1,OR(B2=$J$1,B1=$J$1)),AND(D2=D3,E2=E3,OR(B2=$J$1,B3=$J$1))),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Autofill all cells below G2. If you get TRUE in the desired rows, use the value in column G for the conditional formatting